# How make appears a field from the field list automatically?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I just started to use Access with vba. I have table with roles, years and its workload of each role in this specific year. Each record in the table is IDRole, IDYear,Workload (number). 
I display the table in a form doing a crosstab table where the years are in the columns and the roles in the rows. The number of years can increase.

My problem is when I add new years and display in the columns, it doesn't appear in the form so I have to select from the field list manually but I would like to know if there is any way in  VBA that when the form is load, automatically appears the new columns (years).

Comment: Can't you use a PivotTable form ? Which version of Access are you using ?

Comment: When you mentioned crosstab, I thought crosstab query.  But you actually said crosstab *table*.  Is your data source a table or a query?

Comment: My problem is that I need to modify the data in the table. It is possible with a PivotTable form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood your situation.  Your form's crosstab data source is actually a table instead of a query.  And as you add columns to that table, you want the new columns to automatically appear in the form when you next open the form.

In that case, use the approach described below, but where I selected a query (*Query.qryFoo2*) in the *Source Object* dropdown, choose your table ... *Table.YourTableName* ... in that dropdown.

The last 2 paragraphs below apply whether your data source is a table or query.

---

If you have your crosstab query saved as a named query, you can use it as the *Source Object* for a subform control.

[image]

Then when you switch from Design to Form View, the query results will be displayed in Datasheet View within the subform control.

[image]

As the number of columns changes over time, that Datasheet View can "automagically adapt" to display them ... the same as if you opened the named query directly in Datasheet View.

As far as I'm aware, there is no other reasonably simple way to accomplish what you want.  If this suggestion is not suitable, you can explore programmatically  adding bound data controls to your existing form after examining the set of fields the query currently returns.  But that is way too much effort IMO.

Comment: The problem is that I need to modify this table, no just show it.So at the beginning I show the crosstab query as you say but I couldn't modify the data so I make a query to create a table from the query crosstab and show it and then once the data are modified I programatically store in the original table. The problem is that the form when the table is recreated because a new year is entered in the original table, it doesnt shown the new year when you load the form, but it is in the field list. Is there any way of make it appear automatically? Or any way of can modify the data?

Comment: Use the table as the *Source Object* of a subform control.  I revised this answer.

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much! I was desesperated! Why it works with a subform and not with a form?

Comment: You need a subform control so that Access retrieves the current version of the entire *Source Object* (table, query, report).  For the form itself, there is nothing exactly equivalent to *Source Object*.  You could update the form's *Record Source* as needed, but then you would still need to add data controls (such as text boxes) to accommodate the new fields ... and that would require what I called way too much effort.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue, I have a form which I use to show a Query, And I can't anticipate the number of  columns from the query.

I found the same topic on other pages, and for the moment the only way I found is to build an excel file based on the query.

Another way also is maybe to directly open the crossTab query using vba.